# Is there a simple way to turn this D3 Multi-Line Chart into an Area Chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I am fairly new to D3 and I am trying to make a stacked area chart with no success (similar in looks this one: http://nvd3.org/examples/stackedArea.html).

So far I have a stacked multi-line chart, so I was hoping there might be an easy way to just fill in the color down to the bottom of the graph, but when I try to do the fill, it colors it wrong.  Here is a fiddle to help (although the code doesn't start until line 1707 because the first chunk is the JSON: https://jsfiddle.net/wL04qqk1/2/

In the CSS, I tried making it look like this:

```
.line1 {
  fill: #0066CC;
  stroke: #003D7A;  /*stroke: steelblue;*/
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

But it doesn't fill it in properly.

Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: The example you linked has all the code you need to do what you want. If there are parts of that code you don't understand feel free to post questions about it ;)

Comment: @CoolBlue Okay so I am not sure how to implement that code what I already have, so I guess I will ask in chunks. :)  So, I have the lines that I need, and I just need to color the area underneath the lines.  So in the example I posted, I need to use the `var chart = nv.models.stackedAreaChart()
.margin({right: 100})
.x(function(d) { return d[0] })
.y(function(d) { return d[1] })
.useInteractiveGuideline(true)
.rightAlignYAxis(true)
.transitionDuration(500)
.showControls(true)
.clipEdge(true);`  part somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the updated fiddle at: https://jsfiddle.net/wL04qqk1/3/

I added the style staight to the paths you are plotting see below:

```
 var path4 = graph.append("g")
     .append("path")
     .data([data4])
     .attr("class", "line4")
     .style({'fill':'red'});
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I've done that before and it's close to what I want, but I would like the red fill on the top line to go all the way to the bottom, then the green line to be overtop of the red line with the green filling going all the way to the bottom of the graph, and so on. Does that make sense? Do you know how to help me?

Comment: Is this the kind of chart you're looking to do? http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885211

Comment: Yes very similar to that - I was just hoping I wouldn't have to change my whole code from what I had right now because I'm not quite sure how to implement that example in your comment.

Comment: I know I've played around with it quite a bit but I can't figure out how to apply it to my situation.  Probably because I'm not quite sure what the code is doing, but could you help me understand?  Is it the `.map(function(name))` part that I need?  Or is it the chunk about appending the "path" and the style is fill?

Comment: Please see updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wL04qqk1/5/ ... it is not very pretty and may not be 100% accurate but it should get you on the way.